# XPages: disabled property breaks required computation for xp:inputText

Tags: xpages

On my application I have an xp:inputText control with the disabled property set to true and the required property computed as followed:

```
<xp:inputText 
    id="txtSecurityLevel"
    styleClass="form-control-static"
    value="#{employeeBean.employee.securityLvl}" 
    disabled="true" 
    >
    <xp:this.validators>
        <xp:validateRequired
            message="Unsufficient level of security">
        </xp:validateRequired>
    </xp:this.validators>
    <xp:this.required><![CDATA[#{javascript:return submittedBy("btnProceed")}]]></xp:this.required>
</xp:inputText>
```

The value of the field is pre-populated and I do not want users to alter the value.

When I use the same approach for other inputText controls but with the disabled property set to false the validation is initiated for these fields.

Is there another approach I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the field non-editable, use the `readonly` property.

Internet Explorer used to allow the `disabled` and `readonly` property interchangeably. But with IE10 they changed the behaviour so `disabled` worked as in other browsers, i.e. the value is not passed from the browser to the server. Because it's not passed back from the browser, your validation fails. `disabled` is for an input that should be unusable for the browser, see https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_input_disabled.asp. What you want is for it to be readonly for the user.